how is this patent for matching "intentions" or "commitment disposition" for dating apps novel or non-obvious?
https://patents.google.com/patent/US12019694B1/en?inventor=Maxim+Cheremkhin
almost all dating apps have features for users to select their "relationship goals". For example, "serious relationship", "long term", "short term", "casual", "new friends", "hookups".
Once selected, the "relationship goal", then acts as an additional filter to find matches with the same or similar "relationship goals".
I am not sure when the "relationship goals" feature was first introduced and by who. But I am almost sure that it predates the patent above. And if they do not predate the above patent, all of these apps currently would be infringing on this patent?
The patent above

claim:
1. A computer implemented method, comprising:
receiving, from a client device, matching criteria specified by a first individual at a first time in a sequence of time steps, the matching criteria including an indication of an intention for a relationship specified by the first individual at the first time, wherein the intention is selected from a range of available intentions, and wherein the selected intention can be modified at a second time in the sequence of time steps;
for each time in the sequence of time steps, generating a match between the first individual and at least one individual in a pool of individuals based upon the matching criteria, including identifying the at least one individual in the pool of individuals having an intention at the time for a relationship that is consistent with the intention specified by the first individual;
transmitting to the client device data configured to cause the client device to display:
(a) an indication of the match between the first individual and the at least one individual in the pool of individuals, and
(b) an indication of the intention for a relationship for the at least one individual at the time for display with the match, wherein the indication of the intention for the at least one individual comprises a presentation of a particular intention selected from the range of available intentions, wherein the presentation of the particular intention selected from the range of available intentions comprises a graphical user interface element identifying the particular intention;
collecting a match acceptance from the client device for the at least one individual; and
in response to the match acceptance, enabling network communication between the first individual and the at least one individual.

The only point that I can think of is that the patent does narrow down its definition for "intentions" to a numeric scale in the specifications:

...A slider bar 304 with a feature 306 may be used to specify the commitment disposition between a high level (e.g., “Mr. Right”) and a low level (e.g., “Mr. Right Now”)...
...However, an overriding filter condition is commitment disposition criterion, which must match within some specified range (e.g., two individuals may not deviate in position on the slider 304 in FIG. 3 by more than 25%)...
...The commitment disposition criterion discussed m connection with FIG. 3 may be referred to as a “mood scale”. The feature 306 can be moved on scale 304 between different ‘moods’. Moving the indicator button 306 on scale 304 serves two purposes for the user...
...Through the use of the indicator scale users are able to indicate what their intentions are as they look for matches, and also filter the other users available to view...

Questions:

Given the language in the specifications, must the term "intention" in the claims be defined narrowly as a "numeric scale"?
If (1) is accurate, doesn't it still render it obvious in light of the existence of prior art, which are "relationship goals"?
Who currently owns the rights to US12019694B1. The assignees is confusing.


If you are going to quote a claim, you need to quote the whole claim. One brief phrase out of a very long claim doesn't really mean much.

fixed .... @EricS

Without studying the record of the prosecution and examination it’s hard to say definitively but I share your impression that this doesn’t seem like it is as new in 2022.
I gave a quick look at the file and there was one non-final rejection, an amendment and the eventually an allowance.
In response to
several claims rejected under 35 U.S.C. § 103 as allegedly being unpatentable over Blank (U.S. 2002/0103792) and Perry (U.S. 2018/0285986)
The applicant added this language in the amendment-

as between the first individual and individuals in a pool of individuals based upon the matching criteria, including identifying one or more
individuals in the pool of individuals having a commitment disposition within a range of the commitment disposition specified by the first individual, wherein an extent of the range is determined based at least ni part on the commitment disposition specified by the first individual,
the range including the commitment disposition specified by the first individual and at least one other commitment disposition," and "supplying to the client device data for display on a
graphical user interface, the data including...(b) an indication of a commitment disposition of
each of the one or more individuals for display with respective matches, the commitment disposition for each individual indicative of a level of commitment of the individual for a dating
relationship, wherein the indication of the commitment disposition of each individual comprises an identification of a particular one of multiple available commitment dispositions


actually, this patent was a continuation from one originally filed in 2018 - US11386172B1

given that this patent was granted, does it have to power to sue Tinder, Hinge, Okcupid, CMB, etc. for infringement? I have not heard of such lawsuit yet.

If  the owner, Bumble, goes after these they are tangling with The Match Group which owns over thirty sites including most you list. It may be they have licensed it, cross licensed it or are waiting to use it defensively.

Does it matter that in the specifications, the patent does provide a narrow definition of what "commit disposition" means? It defines it as a "numeric scale", inputted by a "slider bar", with "high values", "low values", and "central values". This indicates that the "commitment disposition" is range of values with inherent numeric order. Thus if the scope is limited to this, then the "relationship goals" of popular apps would not infringe, as non of them are "numeric scales" with inherent order?

Also, what do you mean by using it defensively?

Used only in a counter suit if they come after Bumble.

actually, the current Assignee of the patent is Citibank NA. That's according to the last assignment listed on google and the USPOTO

@BearBileFarmingisTorture Claim 1 is exceptionally long. This essentially means it is very narrow. An infringer would have to implement each and every step in the claim.

@EricS It sounds long, but in reality all of the steps in Claim 1 are standard steps for almost all dating apps. Can you point to something from Claim 1 that isn't a standard step in a dating app?

@BearBileFarmingisTorture I’ve never used a dating app so I can’t say.

@BearBileFarmingisTorture - the BofA has recorded a security interest. It’s not an assignment but might show that it is part of collateral in a loan.
